# Linux reproduce error about Transparent Huge Page

Tags: linux, huge-pages

I've been doing stress test to check if some process stall error comes out once memory got high load (THP)Transparent Huge Page is enable.

I want to reproduce the error '**Random 'stalls' ocurring often up to several minutes - broken transparent hugepage support'**.
ref. https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5716

> so I prepared the VM cpu: 8 mem: 64

so I make sure the THP is enabled.

`[root@localhost ~]# cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
[always] madvise never`

so I run the command below to put 90% loads on the mem.

```
stress --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemFree/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep -m 1
```

And then check the `/var/log/messages`

`dmesg`

However nothing comes out.

Coudld you please suggest some tip to reproduce the same error?

Comment: Install redhat natively on bare metal, not in VM.

Comment: It is a low level bug caused by wrong handling of hardware. If you run a patched kernel as host os (which handles memory well), then you won't notice hw driver bugs in VM.